# Code Gives No Errors but Does Nothing in Command Prompt

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation

I am having trouble getting my code to run on command prompt, I am getting no errors but when I run the code nothing happens.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;
//defines the maximum queue size 
#define MAX_QUE_SIZE 10
//creates the "rules" for the queue
class queue {
private:
int A[MAX_QUE_SIZE];
int front;
int rear;

public:
queue() {
    front = -1;
    rear = -1;
}

//checks to see if the queue is empty
bool isEmpty() {
    return (front == -1 && rear == -1);
}

//checks to see if the queue if full
bool isFull() {
    return (rear + 1) % MAX_QUE_SIZE == front ? true : false;
}

//checks to see if the queue is full, if not then it adds to the queue.
//if so it gives an error message.
void enqueue(int element) {
    if (isFull()) {
        throw std::overflow_error("QUEUE FULL");
    }
    if (isEmpty()) {
        front = 0;
        rear = 0;
    }
    else {
        rear = (rear + 1) % MAX_QUE_SIZE;
    }
    A[rear] = element;
}

//checks to see if the queue is empty, if not then it deletes from the queue
//if sos it gives an error message.
void dequeue() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw std::underflow_error("QUEUE EMPTY");
    }
    else if (front == rear) {
        rear = -1;
        front = -1;
    }
    else {
        front = (front + 1) % MAX_QUE_SIZE;
    }
}

//checks to see if the queue is empty, if so it gives a message saying so
//if not then it prints all the items in the queue

void printqueue() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        cout << "EMPTY QUEUE";
    }
    else {
        int count = (rear + MAX_QUE_SIZE - front) % MAX_QUE_SIZE + 1;
        cout << "Queue       : ";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int index = (front + i) % MAX_QUE_SIZE;
            cout << A[index] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
}
};

int main()
{
queue Q; // creating an instance of Queue. 
int i;
int k = 0;
int x;

std::cout << "Please enter some integers (enter 0 to exit):\n";
//a do-while statement that adds to the queue
do {
    std::cin >> i;
    //tries to add to the queue, if the queue is full it gives and overflow error
    try {
        Q.enqueue(i);
    }
    catch (std::overflow_error e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
} while (i != 0);
std::cout << endl;
Q.printqueue();

std:cout << "How many values do you want to dequeue:\n";
std::cin >> x;
cout << endl;
//a for loop that dequeues the number of items the user wants to delete
//try the foor loop and dequeue function, if the queue is empty then it gives an underflow error
try {
    for (int k = 0; k < x; k++) {

        Q.dequeue();
    }
}
    catch (std::underflow_error e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << endl;
    }


Q.printqueue();

return 0;
 }
```

I am also typing in g++ -o ehQue ehQue.cpp to compile it. I am not sure if this is causing the error or if my code itself is causing the error. Any amount of help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's sub-optimal to read. Please work on your formatting/indentation.

Comment: Works fine here with input `1 2 3 4 5 0`, except that the terminating 0 is also enqueued,

Comment: *I am getting no errors but when I run the code nothing happens* -- When something like this happens, take a step back and strip your code down to make sure you are getting input.  Then add code until you are not able to get input.  But that begs the question -- you added all of this code all at once without running it, i.e. develop incrementally?

Comment: This is what a debugger is for.  Hardly what SO is for.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're just not executing your code. It compiles and runs.

You're compiling the program (not executing it) with:

```
g++ -o ehQue ehQue.cpp
```

The command can be understood as calling the program "g++" which should be just an alias to "gcc" which is the compiler. It takes sources code and produces object code, which is then linked to produce an executable binary (program.)

```
-o ehQue
```

Is the command parameter to specify the output file name. The compiler will take the provided files and (attempt to) produce a working executable called "ehQue".

```
ehQue.cpp
```

Is your source code, which you specified to the compiler.

Within your terminal (where you typed the g++ command) you will, also, need to call the program using a command such as:

```
./ehQue
```

Or to be specific to the Windows command prompt:

```
ehQue
```

Where you should find that your program runs.

(Tangential) Unless you specifically need to re-invent the wheel, one of CPP's defining features is the Standard Template Library (STL) which is part of the core specification... wrapping a [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) in a class with your print functions would be advisable.